# Streaming Video Arduino - Touch Designer

Tags: camera, arduino, streaming

Could I send an image or video from Arduino IDE to Touch Designer software?
Could I use the pictures saved with the CMOS camera for example?

Thanks,
Giuseppe

Answer (score 1):

You can send images via bluetooth, wifi or serial, but the speed of taking the picture and sending over wont be that fast.

You are better of with a gopro connected via wifi or Canon via usb cable. Forget Arduino if you need a live feed.